# Weak convergence of probability measures on uncountable product space

Tags: probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider  $\mathbb{R}^T$, the space of real-valued functions defined on an **uncountable** index set $T$, equipped with the product topology (i.e., the coarsest topology such that each projection mapping is continuous). It is known that $\mathbb{R}^T$ is not metrizable (not even first countable). Consider probability measures $P_n$, $P$,  $n\in \mathbb{N}$, defined on the Borel $\sigma$-field on $\mathbb{R}^T$. Although one rarely talks about weak convergence of probability measures on a non-metrizable space, let's say we still define the weak convergence $P_n\Rightarrow P$ as $P_n f \rightarrow P f$ for any bounded continuous real-valued function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^T$.

My question is:  is this convergence equivalent to the convergence of finite-dimensional distributions, i.e., $P_n  \circ \pi_{I}^{-1}\Rightarrow P \circ \pi_I^{-1}$ on $\mathbb{R}^I$, where $I$ is a finite subset of $T$ and $\pi_I:\mathbb{R}^T\mapsto \mathbb{R}^I$ is the projection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The problem reduces to the case of countable products. By a theorem of Bockstein, which I learned [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/364126/35357), every continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^T\to\mathbb{R}$ can depend only on countably many coordinates.

Comment: Thank you! That is an interesting result.

Comment: Do you know a source for the specific fact that is being asked about i.e. given a sequence $X_n$ of random variables taking values in a product space like $\mathbf{R}^T$ where $T$ is uncountable, the convergence of finite-dimensional distributions implies the convergence in the form $\int g d\mu_{X_n} \to \int g d\mu_X$?

Comment: @T_M The answer accepts the premise of the question that it works for $T$ countable and reduces to that result. I don't have a reference for the premise at hand.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker thank you. I originally asked my question in this form: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451568/what-are-the-correct-sigma-algebras-topologies-for-convergence-in-distribution and then afterwards found this page. I'm trying to understand what weak convergence of random fields should mean.

Comment: @T_M I'm not really familiar with random fields, but it seems you are also looking for material on weak convergence in nonmetrizable spaces. There is material in volume 2 of Bogachev's "Measure Theory" and also in his more readable "Weak Convergence
of Measures".

Comment: Thanks very much for the references!